# How to clear a batch in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am trying to reuse a prepared statement when executing multi-inserts. Something like

```
InsertValuesStepN<Record> batch = create.insertInto(table, fields);
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    batch.values();
    if(i % 1000 == 0) {
        batch.execute();
        // need to call clearBatch here so we don't insert records twice
    }
}
```

but I don't see any way to have InsertValuesStepN clear it's records after calling execute. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

#### Create a new statement for each batch:

You could create a new statement on each batch, instead of reusing the previous one.

```java
InsertValuesStepN<Record> batch = null;
for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    if (batch == null)
        batch = create.insertInto(table, fields);

    batch.values();
    if(i % 1000 == 0) {
        batch.execute();
        batch = null;
    }
}
```

#### Using the `bind()` API

This is usually not recommended because of performance issue [#6616](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6616), but since your bottleneck (as per your comment) is with creating a new prepared statement, you might try to use the `Query.bind()` API which you could use on your 2nd, 3rd, etc. batch to replace existing bind values with new ones in an existing query. Call [`Query.bind()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Query.html#bind(int,java.lang.Object)) like this:

```java
// Create the initial statement with dummy values for your batch
Query batch = create.insertInto(table, fields).values(...).keepStatement(true);
for(int i=0; i<100000; i += 1000) {

    // Call this once for each bind value
    batch.bind(...);
    batch.execute();

    // Handle the last insertions, where you have less than 1000 rows per insert
    // ...
}
```

#### Proxy JDBC

You could implement a proxy JDBC `PreparedStatement` that doesn't actually close the delegate statement when jOOQ calls `PreparedStatement.close()`, but keeps it open and offers the same statement again to jOOQ when jOOQ tries to prepare it again.

There's a pending feature request to offer such a `PreparedStatement` cache out of the box: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7327, or maybe, your JDBC driver already has one (e.g. Oracle does).

#### Using the import API

But perhaps, you're actually using for [jOOQ's import API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/), which allows for specifying the batch, bulk, and commit sizes, e.g.

```java
create
   .loadInto(table)
   .bulkAfter(1000)
   .loadArrays(...) // There are other possible data sources
   .fields(fields)
   .execute();
```

Comment: Thanks but the import API doesn't keep the statement open between bulk inserts. I am seeing calls to close and open prepared statement after each insert. This normally wouldn't be a problem but I am seeing it take ~20 seconds to open the prepared statement.

Comment: @TrevorKramer: Interesting, it's worth exploring keeping open statements indeed. This is possible with the `Query.keepStatement()` API (which I'm assuming you called, but omitted in your question), but not with the `loadInto()` API. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10432. What warrants 20 seconds for opening the statement? This does seem excessive, nonetheless...

Comment: I've updated the answer with a suggestion of the [`Query.bind()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Query.html#bind(int,java.lang.Object)) method, which I normally don't suggest because of an open client-side performance issue (do measure if it affects you).

Comment: I also had the problem and switched to import api, however as a side node it seems batch.bind + batch.execute does not clear the batch so on the next execute I get unique constraint exception due to the same lines inserted as in previous execute.

Comment: @stryba: If you think there's a use-case for clearing batches, you could request it here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. It doesn't seem like something that should be done out of the box, but there might be room for a `clearBatch()` method, just like in JDBC.

Comment: @LukasEder thanks for answering, so execute should not clear the batch? This was my expectation though.

Comment: @stryba: This isn't a good place for discussing what jOOQ *should do*. Can you please create a feature request, etc.?